# Two validators for one single entity in DTO

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, nestjs

Are there any ways or would it be possible to have two validator in one single entity? Like for the given example code below, the `identifier` would accept an email as its payload but it would also accept
number/mobile number as its payload as well.

```
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  identifier: string;
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried,

```
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  @IsPhoneNumber('US')
  identifier: string;
```

But it does not work.

**EDIT 2:**
I found a reference code based on this previous thread, [How to use else condition in validationif decorator nestjs class-validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68610924/how-to-use-else-condition-in-validationif-decorator-nestjs-class-validator), and I copied his validation class.

```
import { ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface, ValidationArguments } from "class-validator";
import { IdentifierType } from "../interface/access.interface";

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'IdentifierValidation', async: false })
export class IdentifierValidation implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    validate(identifier: string, args: ValidationArguments) {

        if (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args.object)).type === IdentifierType.MOBILE) {

            var regexp = new RegExp('/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im');
            // "regexp" variable now validate phone number.
            return regexp.test(identifier);
        } else {
            regexp = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$");
            // "regexp" variable now validate email address.
            return regexp.test(identifier);
        }

    }

    defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {

        if (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args.object)).type === IdentifierType.MOBILE) {
            return 'Enter a valid phone number.'
        } else {
            return 'Enter a valid email address.'
        }
    }
}
```

DTO -

```
export class VerifyOtpDto {
  @Validate(IdentifierValidation)
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  identifier: string;

  @ApiProperty({ enum: IdentifierType })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  identifierType: IdentifierType;
}
```

ENUM -

```
export enum IdentifierType {
  EMAIL = 'email',
  MOBILE = 'mobile',
}
```

It does work with email but trying to feed a mobile number still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to do this, first with regex:

```
@Matches(/YOUR_REGEX/, {message: 'identifier should be email or phone'})
identifier: string;
```

Or you can get the idea from [this](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/160#issuecomment-373950634):

```
@IsType(Array<(val: any) => boolean>)
@IsType([
 val => typeof val == 'string',
 val => typeof val == 'boolean',
])
private readonly foo: boolean | string;
```

Comment: Hi @Vahid, thanks for your input! I have updated the post. Any help on the current custom class validation would be really helpful. For the meantime, I'll take a look at your suggestion. 

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can get more than one validator in one DTO column.

Did you check https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator here?

if you want to check mobile number, you can use to `@IsMobilePhone(locale: string)`.

Comment: Hi @nari120, I have edited my post to further clarify. 

Comment: @user16750862 Hi, how about `en_US` or `en_us` ?

Comment: I have tried but the syntax does not exist.

Comment: Could you check 2 of reference ?

1. [https://github.com/garethhcoleman/NestJS-IssueDemo/blob/master/src/user/user-create.dto.ts](https://github.com/garethhcoleman/NestJS-IssueDemo/blob/master/src/user/user-create.dto.ts)
2. [https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/366](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/366)

Comment: Oh I think you may have missed my point.  I wanted to make identifier to accept both email and mobile number as payload but I think it is not possible.